# Sync my "Sites" folder with iCloud Drive?

Tags: macos, apache

I am worried about my localhost files, so I want to sync them with iCloud Drive. After some attempts to do it all I get on my `http://localhost` is 403 Forbidden error.

I've tried what I've done with my `~/Downloads` folder — just replacing it with an alias to `~/Documents/Downloads`, while Documents is syncing with iCloud Drive. But with `~/Sites` folder, which is located, moreover, in the same "Home" folder (`~/`), it doesn't work.

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/dafuqtor/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/dafuqtor/Sites">
```

This is how my localhost directory looks in `httpd.conf` now. But as I said above, when I just change the DocumentRoot and Directory to `"/Users/dafuqtor/Documents/Sites"`, I'm getting 403 trying to access `http://localhost`.

I have looked into `/var/log/apache2/error_log`. For the first time, it said `Cannot serve directory ... server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`, so I added `Options +Indexes` to `httpd.conf`.
Now error_log gives me this when I'm trying to access localhost:

```
access to / denied (filesystem path '/Users/dafuqtor/Documents/Sites') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Comment: Apache normally logs errors in /var/log/apache2/error_log. Start by looking there.

Comment: @TurePålsson now error_log gives me this — `access to / denied (filesystem path '/Users/dafuqtor/Documents/Sites') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path`.

Answer (score 0):

Apache normally runs as the user `_www`, and `~/Documents` normally has its permissions set so that nobody but its owner (i.e, user `dafuqtor`) can access it.

You *could* solve this by using chmod to give everyone at least execute permission on your documents folder (`chmod o+x ~/Documents`) but I don’t particularly recommend this; in combination with a web server it seems to invite mistakes leaving your entire documents directory open to the world!